# cannot find -lGL even though ldconfig shows it's there?

Tags: nvidia, opengl, cuda

I installed nvidia-current for CUDA development which includes `libGL.so`.

`sudo ldconfig -v` shows this output:

```
...
/usr/lib/nvidia-current:
    libnvidia-compiler.so.195.36.24 -> libnvidia-compiler.so.195.36.24
    libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.195.36.24
    libXvMCNVIDIA_dynamic.so.1 -> libXvMCNVIDIA.so.195.36.24
    libnvidia-cfg.so.1 -> libnvidia-cfg.so.195.36.24
    libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.195.36.24
    libnvidia-tls.so.1 -> libnvidia-tls.so.195.36.24
    libOpenCL.so.1 -> libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
    libGLcore.so.1 -> libGLcore.so.195.36.24
...
```

Why can't the linker find this library?

If I run make from the directory I'm trying to compile, the linker can't find. But if I just run `gcc` or `ld` with the `-lGL` flag, it seems to work fine. I get:

```
/usr/lib/../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which seems to me like it's working...but not working with make...

Answer (score 0):

The linker doesn't look in non-standard directories by default. You need to ensure that it's looking in `/usr/lib/nvidia-current` by using the `-L` flag.

Also, you must have the development files installed. A `libGL.so` symlink must exist, which points to the correct version of the library. Generally though, this should be done against the standard mesa GL library, and the nvidia files should be used at runtime.

Comment: the make command includes this flag (see end)
    g++ -v -msse2 ... -Xlinker -T -Xlinker ptlsim-32bit.lds -L./gpgpusim/lib/release -L/usr/lib/nvidia-current -lgpgpusim -lGL -lm -lz -lpthread #-Wl,--verbose